# Migration of Google Apps Marketplace app to oAuth 2.0 with additional scopes

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We have app using oauth 1.0 in old marketplace. We are in process of migrating to oauth 2.0 for new marketplace. We are using UpgradeableApp API to do migration for existing domains. I am following steps specified here : https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v1migratev2

As mentioned in the prerequisites in the above link: The scopes for the new and old apps must be compatible. But our new app has some additional scopes. Is there any way to grant access to these additional scopes while doing migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only domain's admin or users can approve additional scopes.

Domain's admin receives an email notification after upgrade.

In your oauth2.0 app you can detect if all scopes have been approved or not. If not, you can show the user appropriate message to contact domain admin to get scopes approved.

Answer (score 0):

For this we should have same scope in both old as well as on new listing. I am also facing the same problem of migrating the old users to new one. Kindly check the below code how I am migrating from old to new Users but every time I am getting 401 UnAuthorized, May I know what I am missing for this.

```
String url = String.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/upgradableApp/{0}/{1}/{2}", oldAppId, chromeListing, domain);            
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "PUT";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "OAuth");
        Hashtable postObj = new Hashtable();
        postObj["Consumer Key"] = oldClientId;
        postObj["Consumer Key Secret"] = oldSecret;
        String s1 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(postObj);
        var bs = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s1);
        using (Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            reqStream.Write(bs, 0, bs.Length);
        }
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
            }
        }
```